# DefaultRemoteProxy unknown version,Connect to 10.169.230.222:5558 [/10.169.230.222] failed: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: java, selenium

Trying to launch the selenium grid using VM as hub

Error in the grid console: localhost:4444/grid/console.

syntax that I have given in the cmd of the node machine:

```
java -jar C:\Users\Downloads\selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role 
webdriver -hub http://96.115.132.114:4444/grid/register -port 5558 -host 
10.169.230.222 -browser "browserName=firefox, platform=WINDOWS"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are triying to launch hub and node at the same time.

You should launch two instances of the selenium server (.jar file) one with the hub role and the other one with node role

- **Start Hub**

  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role hub
- **Connect node**

  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role node  -hub http://96.115.132.114:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=firefox, platform=WINDOWS"

More info at the [documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp)